# GetOfficeActivationsUserDetail unexpected error on InvokeWebRequest

Tags: powershell, azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, office365

I want to download the O365 Activation Report via a powershell script where i call the Graph API V1.0.
I successfully get the token but i'm somehow unable to perform the call to retrieve the CSV.
Here is what i do:

```
function getToken()
{
    param(
    )
    $global:appreg = @()
    $global:appreg +=[pscustomobject]@{tenantId="****";appID="****";secret="****";headers=""}
    $global:appreg | % {
        $appreg = $_
        $ReqTokenBody = @{
            Grant_Type    = "client_credentials"
            Scope         = "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default"
            client_Id     = $appreg.appID
            Client_Secret = $appreg.secret
        } 
        $TokenResponse = iwr -Uri "https://login.microsoftonline.com/$($appreg.tenantId)/oauth2/v2.0/token" -Method POST -Body $ReqTokenBody
        $accesstoken = ($TokenResponse | Convertfrom-Json).access_token
        $appreg.headers = @{'Authorization' = 'Bearer ' + $accesstoken;'Content-type' = 'application/json'}
        #$accesstoken 
    }
}

$global:getcallurl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActivationsUserDetail"
$mainTenandID = "****"

getToken
```

up to here no error is shown so i assume the getToken works

```
$result = iwr -uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/reports/getOffice365ActivationsUserDetail"  -Method Get -Headers ($global:appreg |?{$_.tenantID -eq $mainTenandID}).headers
```

After this i get:

> Invoke-RestMethod : The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occurred on a send.

**What am i performing wrong in the call?**

Answer (score 0):

The script is OK.

It's related to TLS setting.

Running `​[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12` before running your script should resolve this issue.